# non-trivial use of `Console` by `wmic.exe`

Tags: c, winapi, console, io-redirection, wmic

In order to wrap some `Windows Console Application` ***interactively*** , I use `pipes` when calling `CreateProcess()` as parameters for `STARTUPINFO::hStdOutput  , STARTUPINFO::hStdInput and STARTUPINFO::hStdError` (for each  there's 2 unique pipes - one for read and the other for write)
This setup works just fine for many known windows-console applications as `net.exe` , `tree.com` , `ipconfig.exe` etc. However it does not work well for `wmic.exe`. while trying to investigate it , I found out `wmic.exe` using few functions of the [Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  family. Its seems like `wmic.exe` is using these function to redefine it's own `IO` properties.

I'm looking for a way to overcome these modification , in order to successfully redirect the `IO` of `wmic.exe` as well.

Comment: Why not directly call into WMI (via its COM interfaces)?

Comment: I already have a general app-wrapper, and would really like to avoid the complication of using `COM` interfaces.

Comment: If `wmic.exe` does more than read standard input for commands the it will be very hard to automate/control it from just standard input. And equivalently for standard output. COM (especially from C without one of the C++ based wrapper/helper libraries) is hard. But in trying to re-use code that cannot, in this case, provide the interface you need (pun intended) better not to waste time failing to force the square peg into the round hole.

Comment: Another thought: how tied are you to `wmic.exe`: might be easier with another WMI wrapper (eg. a PowerShell script) that does not depend on more than standard input/output. (With PowerShell the input could be generating the script (from a template) and then executing for the output.)

Comment: @Richard these are all good points. I'm not too tied to wmic.exe, so I'll check on wrapping the PowerShell. As for wmic.exe, I seriously doubt that it does anything special with the IO .

Comment: @Richard also, I can't find a PowerShell API for native win32/c environment.

Comment: PowerShell can be run from the command line passing the script on the command line or in a file referenced from the command line. Just execute `PowerShell.exe`.

Comment: but what if I'd like to do it interactively, i.e - run once with redirected IO

Comment: You can put the script on the command line... so interactive via redirected input/output works.