# Read the output from the wmic console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, wmic

Okay here's the issue i want to call the wmic.exe that is found in \windows\system32\wbem execute a command and only read the output from there.

I don't want to use wmi using com as per msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx)  and i dont want to execute wmic through cmd.

And i can't get a way of making it work.I read this thread too but no one answered [non-trivial use of `Console` by `wmic.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976242/non-trivial-use-of-console-by-wmic-exe)

I've tried something like this :

```
FILE* pipe = _popen("wmic.exe cpu get", "r"); 
if (!pipe) 
 throw std::exception("error"); 
char buffer[128]; 
std::string output; 
while(!feof(pipe)) 
{ 
 if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL) output += buffer; 
} 

_pclose(pipe); 
std::stringstream oss(output); 
std::vector<std::string> processor_description; 
std::string buffer; 
while (std::getline(oss, buffer)) 
  processor_description.push_back(buffer);
```

Comment: i tried using pipes (_popen and _pclose)

Comment: I've pasted your source code in the question, please do it next time by yourself

Comment: Okay sorry for that ! any ideas about my prob ? <:

Comment: i found this thread too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935739/wmic-to-get-info-in-qt but not answered ( using qt creator)

Comment: Why not to use a working COM example from Microsoft?

Comment: Okay because honestly i will be using qt later (com doesnt work with qt ) and it seems there are few support forums for it. So i said why not make it work on visual c++ 1st and then ill figure out a conversion method.I have searched for days for a solution but 0 results :/

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set wmic = WshShell.Exec("wmic cpu get")

Do While wmic.Status = 0

     WScript.Sleep 100

Loop



msgbox wmic.Status

     If Not wmic.StdOut.AtEndOfStream Then

          Msgbox wmic.StdOut.ReadAll

     End If
```

This is vbscript that works. You have access to same objects.

Remeber that wmic writes unicode nor OEM (cmd.exe) or ANSI (older GUI programs). If reading it as ansi there will probably be character conversions happening.